# How to check if array object value also exists in another object array value?

Tags: php, arrays

How do I check whether the key value of any object within one given array matches the key value of any object within another array?

There are two arrays, `$personorg_terms` and `$org_terms_in_latest_post`.

I want to check whether the value of `name` in one exists in the `name` of another. If so, we should return that `name`.

In the below example, "S4 Capital" is a match and should be returned.

`$personorg_terms` contains:

```
Array
(
    [0] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 7436
            [name] => WPP
            [slug] => wpp
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 7436
            [taxonomy] => company
            [description] => WPP plc is a British multinational advertising and public relations company with its main management office in London, England, and its executive office in Dublin, Ireland.
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 81
            [filter] => raw
            [term_order] => 0
        )

    [1] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 11814
            [name] => S4 Capital
            [slug] => s4-capital
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 11814
            [taxonomy] => company
            [description] => S4Capital is building a purely digital advertising and marketing services business for global, multi- national, regional, local and millennial-driven influencer brands.
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 6
            [filter] => raw
            [term_order] => 0
        )

)
```

`$org_terms_in_latest_post` contains:

```
Array
(
    [0] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 11814
            [name] => S4 Capital
            [slug] => s4-capital
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 11814
            [taxonomy] => company
            [description] => S4Capital is building a purely digital advertising and marketing services business for global, multi- national, regional, local and millennial-driven influencer brands.
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 6
            [filter] => raw
            [term_order] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: Use `array_column()` to get an array of all the `name` properties. Then use `array_intersect()` to find the names that they have in common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this by passing your two object arrays $personorg_terms and $org_terms_in_latest_post

```
function getDuplicateObject($object_arr, $other_object_arr)
{
    $duplicates = array(); 
    foreach($object_arr as $ob1){

        foreach($other_object_arr as $ob2){
            if($ob1->name == $ob2->name)
                array_push($duplicates, $ob1->name); 
        }

    }
    return $duplicates;
}
```

Comment: This works nicely. To bulk out the answer, seems like... for each item in array #1, also loop through each item in array #2. If values match, push them to an array.